# Export and Import Wordpress custom post type including media to JSON

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am not completely sure if this question follows the rules here, but I don't know where else to go.

I currently have a script that I coded that lets me export specific posts from a custom post type. I am able to export taxonomies, post metas, and everything. I have all of this exported to a JSON file. The only thing I am not sure how to handle is media. I have post meta fields that store the attachment ID of images. So how do I take that attachment ID and use it to import the actual image and then update the post meta that held that ID with the new attachment ID that I get after the import?

Comment: Can noone help?

Comment: If you had posted your script or given the actual context (not just described it) then it would probably have gotten more views and perhaps even a response.  As it stands, your question is impossible to answer without knowledge that only you have. Basically, you're asking for custom code, it sounds like, that would interface with your unknown custom code.

I guess a good starting point would have been to look up on the Wordpress Codex how to access the attachments of a custom post type.

Comment: It is OK I coded a custom script to do what I want. I was just looking to see if there was an easier way or if someone else had already come up with something. Either way, my script works so I am good now.